# Programmatically delete empty rows

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is my sheet

[image]

As you can see row 2 and 6 are empty because I manually deleted some products. My question is how to programmatically delete those empty rows and be replaced with the other product-filled rows?

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("my spreadsheet id");
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete All Empty Rows

```
function deleteEmpties() {
  //I would typically prefer SpreadsheetApp.getActive() but I used this because thats what you function contained
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("my spreadsheet id");
  //I would typical prefer using getSheetByName() but I used this because thats what your function contained
  const sh=ss.getSheets()[0];
  const shsr=2;//data start row
  const vs=sh.getRange(shsr,1,sh.getLastRow()-shsr+1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let d=0;//delete counter
  vs.forEach(function(r,i){
    //deletes row if row is completely empty
    if(r.join('').length==0) {
      sh.deleteRow(i+shsr-d++)//increment delete counter on each delete because the rows are leaving the spreadsheet but not the data array
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Just an idea but if you iterate bottom to top you don't need the delete counter

Comment: I used to do it that way but I find that I like it this way much better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for the `Spreadsheet` class: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet

Information on `deleteRow` can be found here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#deleterowrowposition

Example:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("my spreadsheet id");
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
// Rows start at "1" - this deletes the first row
sheet.deleteRow(2);
sheet.deleteRow(6);
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, but ```sheet.deleteRow(2);
sheet.deleteRow(6);``` dont help at all, because i have to delete a lot of products for example. I cant write ```sheet.deleteRow()``` for every line. Do you know a more efficient way?